# Elixir: what is the binary printed in the repl after module definition?

Tags: binary-data, read-eval-print-loop, elixir

I wrote a simple module in the repl:

```
iex(26)> defmodule Adder do
...(26)> def add(a \\ 0, b \\ 0) do
...(26)> a+b
...(26)> end
...(26)> end
{:module, Adder,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 4, 224, 66, 69, 65, 77, 65, 116, 111, 109, 0, 0, 0, 106, 0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 69, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 46, 65, 100, 100, 101, 114, 8, 95, 95, 105, 110, 102, 111, 95, 95, 4, 100, 111, 99, ...>>,
 {:add, 2}}
```

What is the binary printed out after the module definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the BEAM bytecode output as a raw binary. It's used by the compiler to persist the compiled module to a `Elixir.Adder.beam` file when compiling via mix. Modules defined in iex aren't ever persisted to disk, but you can think of it as confirmation that your module was successfully compiled in memory.

Comment: I see. How do I get the binary for distribution purposes, so people can just execute the binary without installing Erlang and Elixir?

Comment: You'll need to look into generating releases. Take a look at https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm, it's the easiest way to build a release with Elixir. It doesn't work with one off modules, but projects, and it bundles the Erlang runtime with it, but overall the package is quite small.